# Delphi consistently building DLLs to the wrong directory

Tags: delphi, linker, delphi-xe2

I've got a group project built in Delphi XE2 that has 3 projects that always build to the wrong folder for one option set. (I've got 4 configurations under Release and Debug, one for our software configurations and one for FastMM and it's only the debug one that I want to use for debugging that always goes in to the wrong folder.  Compiling the project even says it's building to the correct folder, but the DLL always winds up in a different one which I only used once when I was unit testing the code outside of the main project.

I've deleted every associated file, .identcache, .res, .tvsproj (whatever that was) and nothing changed.  One very strange thing I noticed is that I copied one of the projects to configure the second one and mimics the behavior of the one it was copied from and I never even unit tested that one, so it never had that output path configured for it.

Obviously this makes it pretty annoying to debug, I have to copy files in to the correct folder just to do that (I was kind of astonished when it actually worked, because I thought Delphi might expect to find the files in it's output path, but oh well, those things are magic)

Let me know if I can post anything to help, I don't really know what's necessary, I checked the registry for the output path that it is getting built do and found nothing that I thought was of any consequence (nothing related to these projects).

---

One thing I did notice was, because I copied the original project into another project (they're plugins to the same part of the main program) it has the same  and when I try using it in the "Build Group" it automatically selects both projects.  That's one mystery solved, but is *probably* a red herring?

Comment: Works fine here. Perhaps you could supply a simple repro.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I wonder if I could reproduce it, I've got know idea why it happens.  You think this kind of stuff would be better left just on Embarcadero's website?

Comment: Build configurations are stored in *.dproj file so I guess the problem is where; sometimes *.dproj file gets broken, but I never encountered a case like yours.

Comment: @user yep it was busted.

Answer (score 1):

OK so as usually happens, after 3 years of suffering with this when I finally ask the questions I'm lead straight to the answer it appears as if RAD Studio is lying to us.  The configuration shows this:

[image]

but the dproj had this:

[image]

in it.

there were two conditions for cfg_3 and only the last one showed up in RAD Studio, well for some odd reason the build path was taken from the first one (even though it's specified in both).  So, removing the wrong one (the first one) fixed the problem and things are now building to the correct folder.

I had imported the Utils option set when I was testing the library, but when I incorporated the program in to the main program, I removed it.  Somehow it didn't find it's way completely out of the dproj and I guess (not sure why) but it seems like the other library got messed up because it shared a GUID.